# Dart POST form url encoded body

Tags: flutter, dart, post, stripe-payments

Need to post this nested structure ,

```
Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'amount': amount,
    'currency': currency,
    'description' : description,
    'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
    'shipping': json.encode({
                'name':'some name',
                'address':{
                            'city':'some city',
                            'country':'some country',
                          },
                })

  };

  var response = await http.post(
      StripeService.paymentApiUrl,
      body: body,
      headers: StripeService.headers
  );
  return jsonDecode(response.body);
```

Always getting error in Stripe logs ,

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid object",
    "param": "shipping",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

POST data from logs say ,

```
{
  "amount": "500",
  "currency": "USD",
  "description": "payment for xxxx",
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "shipping": "{\"name\":\"some name\",\"address\":{\"city\":\"some city\",\"country\":\"some country\"}}"
}
```

Have tried `Map<String, String>` as well .

Comment: Could you please replace ```json.encode``` by <String,dynamic>. and also with ```address``` object put <String,dynamic> before ```{```

Comment: @ikerfah  tried that , getting error "type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast"

Comment: can you please send me the new code you used just to check ?

Comment: @ikerfah Map<String, dynamic> body = {
  'amount': amount,
  'currency': currency,
  'description' : description,
  'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
  'shipping': <String,dynamic>{
              'name’:’some name',
              'address':<String,dynamic>{
                          'city’:’some city',
                          'country’:’some country',
                        },
              }
};

Comment: Did you notice that there is ```'``` and ```’``` , can you check this is just copy paste issue or you are really using it that way ?

Comment: its a copy paste issue , ignore it , the real issue seems the Map

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224054/discussion-between-sajanyamaha-and-ikerfah).

Comment: please care to explain the downvoting , it is helpful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'amount': amount,
    'currency': currency,
    'description' : description,
    'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
    'shipping[name]': 'some name',
    'shipping[address][city]': 'some city',
    'shipping[address][country]': 'some country',
  };
```

Comment: Amazing , why I missed it !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the body of the post model. Try this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'amount': amount,
    'currency': currency,
    'description' : description,
    'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
    'shipping': {
                'name':'some name',
                'address':{
                            'city':'some city',
                            'country':'some country',
                          },
                }

  };

  var response = await http.post(
      StripeService.paymentApiUrl,
      body: jsonEncode(body), // Encode only the total of post model 
      headers: StripeService.headers
  );
```

Comment: didnt work , it malforms the request , this is the output ,
{
  "{"amount":"500","currency":"USD","description":"payment for neighbro event posting","payment_method_types": [
    {
      "":"card","shipping":{"name":"shipAddress.name","address":{"city":"shipAddress.address.city","country":"shipAddress.address.country","line1":"shipAddress.address.line1","line2":"shipAddress.address.line2","name":"shipAddress.address.name","postalCode":"shipAddress.address.postalCode","state":"shipAddress.address.state"}}}": null
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
: "{\"name\":\"$name\",\"address\":{\"city\":\"$city\",\"country\":\"$country\"}}"
```

Because I think something is wrong on encoding. follow documentation